# How to generate a signing keystore file for PhoneGap Build within Mac OSX?

Tags: android, cordova, keystore

I'm banging my head against a brick wall with this one.

I'm using PhoneGap Build to make an Android application. I have signed up for Android Marketplace and can see the Public Key within.
How do I go on to make a keystore file, an Alias, a key password and a keystore password from here?
I am on Mac OSX.
Thanks in advance!
Chris

Answer (score 4):

I dont know about mac machine, but i am successful to run this command from Ubuntu.

Just issue this command at console:

```
keytool –genkey –v –keystore just2try.keystore –alias just2try –keyalg RSA –validity 10000
```

Once you issue this command at console, it will ask you some question regarding to generate keystore file.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is for Mac OS but for any Windows users who find this question on Google and can't run keytool from the Command Prompt, keytool is available under the "bin" folder of your java installation or %JAVA_HOME%\bin .

If you haven't added java to your PATH variable, you can cd to C:\Program Files\Java-your-jre-version-here\bin and run the keytool program there.