# conditions satisfied by the APK to upload in play store?

Tags: android, google-play

What are all the conditions satisfied by the APK to upload in play store? 
like debug release,signed apk,keystore generation.and please explain them how to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A release build. So you should ensure you are not polluting the logcat with your debugging statements. Usually this will automatically be flagged off for you but you may (as I often did) use different forms of debug logging (eg with the NDK) which will need explicit deactivation.

You will need to sign your APK also. You can generate a key and keystore offline with your development tools (i.e. Android Studio, can't remember about Eclipse but ([How do I generate a "Keystore" for Google Play?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11446121/how-do-i-generate-a-keystore-for-google-play)) should work in that instance).

When you register an account on the playstore you need to upload your public key. You can associate about 20 (IIRC) keys with an app's GMS profile, although that is not strictly required to upload an app in general it is one of the great benefits of a Play Store account. See https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup for more on that.

Then if you are seeking financial reward, either via advertisemnet or direct sales you will need to provide your address.

For this service and also, I suspect, for the purposes of identity verification, Google require a one off registration fee of a princely $25.

Comment: I am getting this "You uploaded an APK that was signed in debug mode. You need to sign your APK in release mode. Learn more about signing."

Comment: You must generate a release key from Android Studio then click Build->Generate Signed APK... Which by happy coincidence is where you need to go to generate a release key.

Comment: I referred https://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html  this to generate but in the creating new keystore i dont know the location of android.jks file they mentioned in first step

Comment: I don't require that file in AS1.3. All files are output. You choose where to place them. It requires no explicit input.