# Where do I find "Public key" and "Private key" for my application apk?

Tags: java, android, google-play, rsa

Where is public and private key of application is located & how to get it ?

Comment: what public and private keys are you referring to?

Comment: Public key and Private key is used when you have to update your application on play store.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11446121/how-do-i-generate-a-keystore-for-google-play

Comment: you are probably trying to build an android apk. There are multiple environments for building apks, you did not specify which one you are using. For debug mode, many environments create keys automatically. For production mode you should carefully read all steps to take and ask questions on stackoverflow if a step does not succeed. Do not ask general question: it doesn't work, help!

Answer (score 2):

Probably you are talking about this:

1.) Create a key using

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

2.) Sign the APK using:

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore my_application.apk alias_name
```

[For details you can look here](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#setup).

Comment: I did the same as you say, but till I don't know where is the private or public key located.

Comment: If you did it via command line my-release-key.keystore contains your keys. If you follow the signing via Android Studio as mentioned in th link, you can get a copy of your keys easily.'

Comment: Please visit the link I've mentioned.